# I have an issue here, with this deprecated tag codes. can anyone fix it?

Tags: html, deprecation-warning

I don't know coding but mannaged to make this code by searching online. But got this SEO warnings:

Warning! Your page is using HTML deprecated tags.

```
<font size="3" color="white">Protejare date</fo....  <font size="3" color="white">Recuperare date</f....  <font size="3" color="white">Revizii generale</....  <font size="3" color="white">Unboxing</font>  <font size="3" color="white">Termeni si Conditi....  <font size="3" color="white">Confidentialitate<....  <font size="3" color="white">Blog Service IT, I....  <font size="4" color="white">© Copyright 2018 ....
```

It needs to be white because of the theme's bad footer options.. My deprecated codes looks like this:

```
<li><a href="https://doradosystems.ro/termeni-si-conditii" title="Termeni si Conditii"><font size="3" color="white">Termeni si Conditii</font></a></li>
```

Can any one of you gifted fellows could fix this code?

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way is to have some [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) separate file, or at least a [`<style>` element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) in your `<head>`.

Otherwise, use a [`<span` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) with a `style=` attribute. If you have some explicit CSS, use a `class=` attribute.

Comment: can you edit a simple code for color using style I guess?

Comment: it worked great!! THANK YOU!! <li><a href="/servicii-it" title="Protejare date"><span style="color:white">Protejare date</span></a></li>